# How to get top 10 customers with most turnover?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to output the **Top 10 customers** with the most turnover.

So, I have a Order collection with this document input example:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId()
  products: Array
  getCartTotalPrice: 100
  owner: ObjectId()
  createdAt: 2020-10-21T14:24:17.918+00:00
  updatedAt: 2020-10-21T14:24:17.918+00:00
  __v: 0
}
```

I have already a solution, where I can output the total turnover from **one specific** customer. Here is an example:

```
//Get total turnover from this client
router.get('/admin/turnover/client/:userID', async (req, res) => {
  const userID = req.params.userID
  const mongoose = require("mongoose");
  let turnoverClient = await Order.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {"owner": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userID)}
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '',
        "totalTurnover": { $sum: '$getCartTotalPrice'}
      }
    }
  ]).exec();

  const turnover = turnoverClient[0] || 0;

  if (turnover == 0) {
    const data = 0
    res.json(data)
  } else {
    const data = turnoverClient[0].totalTurnover.toLocaleString('de')
    res.json(data)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$group` by `owner`, get sum of `getCartTotalPrice`
- `$sort` by `totalTurnover` descending order
- `$limit` 10 documents

```
let Top10Clients = await Order.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$owner",
      totalTurnover: { $sum: "$getCartTotalPrice" }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { totalTurnover: -1 } },
  { $limit: 10 }
]);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IPHWpxQPTO_)